# Scatter plot in Matplotlib: TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('float64') to dtype trying to scatter timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, timedelta

I have a df, one of the columns has the duration of stuff I want to plot. When I run df.info(), it says the type is object. The column reads:

```
Column name
07:25:49
16:14:27
06:55:39
etc
```

I converted to timedelta using pd.time_delta():

```
y = pd.to_timedelta(df['My Column name'])
```

When I print y, I get:

```
1    0 days 07:25:49
2    0 days 16:14:27
3    0 days 06:55:39
etc
dtype: timedelta64[ns] (some of them says 1 or 2 days if it matters)
```

I try to plot like so:

```
x = df['Other column with values'] #when I pull df.info(), this column is float64

plt.scatter(y, x)

Error I get: TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') according to the rule 'same_kind' –
```

If I try to plot it with plt.plot, it works:

[image]

What I wanted to show with this is a correlation between number of images and processing time in a software, so a line graph won't do it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something is wrong with the error you posted

Comment: I think try making `y=pd.to_timedelta(df['My Column name']).dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist on vscode using jupyter notebook, the error cuts right there. I'll run it on other IDE to see

Comment: I don't thing you have an `ypeError`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') according to the rule 'same_kind' - I've updated my question

Comment: @ALollz This worked, thanks! But now my labels go from 0 - 6000, any way to work around this?